# Json parsing exception when json contains "}"

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have a json which contains curly bracket as a value in one of the string field. We are using fasterxml.jackson api for parsing the json and running into errors.

JSON:

```
{
    "Message": {
        "header": {
            "correlationId": "c17da531-bf04-4cbf-9497-631353f9e8c5"
        },
        "body": {
            "log": {
                "id": "a8e5b716-1bc0-4829-bc47-1d28b4ff8920",
                "type": "}test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error"Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value"

How can i continue parsing even when there is } as value ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform you json string to contain escape chars.

My Working Example

```
String json = "{\n" +
                "    \"Message\": {\n" +
                "        \"header\": {\n" +
                "            \"correlationId\": \"c17da531-bf04-4cbf-9497-631353f9e8c5\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        \"body\": {\n" +
                "            \"log\": {\n" +
                "                \"id\": \"a8e5b716-1bc0-4829-bc47-1d28b4ff8920\",\n" +
                "                \"type\": \"}test\"\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";

        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `}` from your json data. like `\}`. But if it is the case you can not change the json (may be you are getting it from some API) the you can just pre-process the json String before parse. like

- You can use regex for this `"\.*(\}).*"`
- Then simply replace the `Group 1.` match from the String.